Issues with AT2020 + UMC22 Setup
I recently bought an AT2020 XLR mic and a Behringer  U-Phoria UMC22.
I can't get any decent sound from this mic, it's either extremely low volume and/or very noisy/hissy. Some information:
-I'm speaking to the correct side of the mic.
-I've turned on 48v Phantom power from the little switch behind the interface.
-I see all the lights show up but my 'SIG' just barely blinks unless I make hella loud noise myself.
-Gain is all the way up to the max and it becomes extremely dirty and noisy when I do that.
-When using my ATH-M40x plugged into the interface and enable the 'Direct Monitor' button, it's VERY noisy, with or without the microphone plugged in that port is always dirty sounding.
-I've tried 3 balanced XLR cables (1 old, 1 new, 1 burrowed, all seem perfectly working)
-I've plugged everything in and out a couple of times to see if I got a bad contact.
-I've tried on both my desktop PC and my macbook pro.
-I've tried a low end no brand aliexpress audio interface from a friend, it's very low in volume even with gain to the max but it sounds miles better to my UMC22 setup.
-I've tried a passive 48v mic preamp (a friend borrowed it to me), when I plug it in I get NO incoming sound at all from the mic, like there's not even enough power for it.
.
At this point I don't know if
-the at2020 is requiring more power than what i'm providing? Maybe I need to purchase an active phantom power 48v xlr preamp to boost the volume.
-I should buy a different mic? Like I got a bad one or something?
-I should blame it on the UMC22 entirely?
Things I have Not tried:
-Buying a different USB cable. Which seems dumb as the one I have came with the UMC22 and looks nice and has that filtering cylindrical thingy.
-Other mics with the UMC22
-active preamps.
Any advice? Thanks.

There’s no such thing as a “passive 48V mic preamp”. What exact make and model was that device? Do you have any other mics to try with the UMC22? Can you confirm that the XLR cables you’ve used are XLR on both ends?

hi @ToddWilcox thanks for responding, the device my friend lent me was the
Klark Teknik MIC BOOSTER CM-1

also @ToddWilcox also yes I can confirmed the cables are balanced xlr cables. I might have to see if someone can borrow me a mic to try

A cable can be balanced with non-XLR connectors, such as with TRS connectors. The fact that it’s balanced doesn’t mean it’s also XLR. I wanted to double check that it’s XLR on both ends, not whether it’s balanced.

Confirmed, the CM-1 adds 25 dB of gain, so it is an active device, not passive. You can’t use the CM-1 with a condenser mic, it uses the phantom power and doesn’t pass it along to the mic. So that won’t work.

Update: ended up buying a $40 preamp that I found on a local store. It supplies 48v phantom power, has a very nice gain dial, and powers from dc12v
I turned off the UMC22  48v phantom power, set the mic gain on it to 30%.
I hooked the preamp output to the UMC22 with my current XLR cables and the At2020 to the preamp's input.
I enabled 48v on the preamp and set gain to 30%
It sounds amazing, the mic finally has very good and clear volume, and no noise!
If you are someone with a UMC22 and a At2020, and have issues like this it's because the UMC22 has not enough juice to power it properly.
